# Relational design - one "many to many" and two "one to many" "between" two tables

Tags: sql-server, relational

I have the following (simplified) app requirement for which I need to create a database in SQL Server:

- entity A is in a many to many relationship with entity B
- entity A is in a one to many relationship with entity C
- entity B is in a one to many relationship with entity C as well.

I modeled this with the following tables:

A (a PK)

B (b PK)

A_B(a FK A(a), b FK B(b), PK(a,b))

C (c PK, a FK A(a), b FK B(b))

Obs. From the (extended) spec: one can have a pair (a,b) in A_B that doesn't exist in C.

1. Is this a good design? I'm asking because obviously you can insert a pair (a,b) in table C that doesn't exist in table A_B, the latter being responsible for associating As to Bs.
2. One could create a trigger on C to do the above check, but this solution would be at the implementation level.
3. Another option would be to create a composite FK on (a,b) in C. I never used them before, so again my question would if is it ok to proceed like this.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You've gone too far in abstracting the problem, I think. You can't ask *us* whether it's an issue that you can have entries in C that don't exist in `A_B`, which seems to be what you're asking in question 1. If your question (as 2 & 3 seem to point to) is how can you *prevent* that situation, then yes, 3 would appear to be the correct choice.

Comment: Definitely it's an issue to have entries in C that don't exist in A_B. Rereading 1 now I realize it's ambiguous. 
My intended question was: given that you shouldn't be able to add an entry (a,b) in C for which a corresponding one doesn't exist in A_B, what is the correct design? As I understand, a FK in C on (a,b) seems to be the right choice. Thank you! 
I can't see how to mark your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a foreign key from `C` to `A_B` will prevent entries appearing in `C` that don't appear in `A_B`. Something like:

```
 CREATE TABLE A (a char(3) not null, constraint PK_A PRIMARY KEY (a));

 CREATE TABLE B (b char(7) not null, constraint PK_B PRIMARY KEY (b));

 CREATE TABLE A_B(
    a char(3) not null,
    b char(7) not null,
    constraint PK_A_B PRIMARY KEY(a,b),
    constraint FK_A_B_A FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A(a),
    constraint FK_A_B_B FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES B(b)
 );

 CREATE TABLE C (
    c char(19) not null,
    a char(3) not null,
    b char(7) not null,
    constraint PK_C PRIMARY KEY (c),
    constraint FK_C_A FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES A(a),
    constraint FK_C_B FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES B(b),
    constraint FK_C_A_B FOREIGN KEY (a,b) REFERENCES A_B(a,b)
 );
```

It's up to you whether you continue to have `FK_C_A` and `FK_C_B`. In the above model, they're redundant, but if, say, `a` and/or `b` in `C` is nullable then it makes sense to keep them separately to enforce the foreign keys when the values aren't all non-`NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use join in sql like:

```
  select A.*, B.*, C1.*, C2.* from A 
    left outer join B on A.id=B.id
    left outer join C as C1 on A.id=C1.id
    left outer join C as C2 on B.id=C2.id
    -- Where condition as per requirement
```